# Error while adding hashmap as a CollectionTable via JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I have an entity with the following fields:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String title;

private Float price;

private String description;

@Lob
private byte[] cover;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@CollectionTable(name="track")
@MapKeyColumn(name="position")
@Column(name="title")
private Map<Integer,String> tracks = new HashMap<>();
```

When I am trying persist an instance of this entity to database I am getting the error: 'CD_ID' is not a column in table or VTI 'APP.TRACK'

I believe I need to use join_column. What is the correct workaround of the problem?

Comment: you have 3 columns in the table "TRACK" : "POSITION", "TITLE", and the join back to the owning entity. So what have you got in your table? JPA will provide a default name for it based on the owning entity. Did you create your schema before hand?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the name of collection table: it should be cd_track not just track

Comment: and how could anyone know that from the info in the question? do you post what you separately generated the schema as? Nope. So delete the question if you simply made a typo